# How can I split a string with numbers and output the results into different rows/columns?

Tags: excel, vba

I have some strings in Col E of my worksheet, and I want to extract "01" and "201912032345000" out into Row F and Row G respectively. For "2019120324500", I hope to add a space in between as well, resulting in "20191203 234500".

The numbers can be variable; the characters, delimiter, and words will never change, except that sometimes it comes with a file extension:

E.g 1

hometeastrash_beehivetester01trash_tepotts20191203234500tepotsFile

E.g 2

hometeastrash_beehivetester01trash_tepotts20191203234500tepotsFile.txt

Here's a picture of what the desired result would look like:

[image: FinalResult]

I have tried the split function using `wks.Cells(BlankRow, 6).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Split(File.Name, "_"))`, however it only extracted "hometeatrash" to Row F whereas I wish to extract "01" from the filename.

Answer (score 2):

In this case I assumed that the number of characters with the numbers does not change.

```
 Sub test()
    Dim xLen As Long
    Dim xStr As String, xNum As String
    Dim StringToSearch As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

'Change accordingly
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        StringToSearch = .Range("E1").Value 'Change accordingly

        xLen = VBA.Len(StringToSearch)

        For i = 1 To xLen

            xStr = VBA.Mid(StringToSearch, i, 1)

            If InStr("0123456789", xStr) Then

                xNum = xNum & xStr

            End If

        Next i
        .Range("F1") = Left(xNum, 2)
        .Range("G1") = Right(xNum, 14)
        .Range("G1").NumberFormat = "#"
    End With

End Sub
```